# git - handling multiple pull requests that may have conflicts

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using gitlab, and I have a protected branch. I have developers submitting pull requests for issues they are solving.

For a few reasons, I cannot merge the changes in immediately, and I want developers to continue working on the next issue.

What I foresee happening are unknown merge conflicts from the guidance I've given them. These are the steps I generally have the developers take when fixing issues for protected branches.

1. Checkout and pull the protected branch
2. Checkout a new branch labeled IssueA from protected branch
3. Fix issues
4. Submit pull request to merge IssueA into protected branch

Now they work on IssueB, starting at step 1. When they get to step 4 they have no conflicts and submit IssueB with no problems.

However, now as the merger I merge in IssueA and now maybe IssueB has a conflict (because the developer did not have IssueA merged in when starting at step 1.)

How can I resolve this without having to immediately merge in changes. I'm not sure if I should have developer merge in IssueA into their IssueB before submitting pull request. That doesn't seem right though because viewing IssueD for example and seeing so many other changes. Do I just reject IssueB, but I'd rather the developer fix conflicts while the issue was fresh in their mind.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In the situation you have described, it is common for the feature developer to be responsible for making sure their pull request is up-to-date with respect to changes in `master` (or whichever branch they are targeting in their pull request).

In a project with a number of developers working on overlapping files, you *expect* to see conflicts. It's a normal part of doing business.

Your developers should rebase their pull requests on `master` (or possibly merge `master` into their pr, depending on the workflow you prefer).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. They are working from the latest `master` but `master` on the remote may have unmerged features... how can the developer hedge the conflicts that may result when they develop FeatureB without FeatureA existing in the remote

Comment: Sure, that's typical. I don't think that changes the nature of my answer. When one of those unmerged features merges, anyone with open pull requests effected by the merge will need to update their pull request so that it merges cleanly.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, didn't know if that was a common ask of a pull request submitter. I guess I would like the developer to have time fixing these potential conflicts before waiting for remote to contain the feature.